# Bintray resource limits

Tags: bintray

An open source project which I know is using bintray currently to deploy their build binaries via travis or appveyor. But when we upload, we get the message 'Error uploading artifact to BinTray (403 status): Account resource usage limits were met for 'projectname'. Isn't bintray storage unlimited for opensource projects?

Answer (score 9):

Related to the question you have asked, Bintray storage is not unlimited to opensource projects. If you wish to have unlimited storage you have to [upgrade your Bintray account](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/premium/premium_upgradingtopremium.html).

Bintray is a cloud platform that gives you full control over how you publish, store, promote, and distribute your software.

Here is a link you can read more about [Bintray key concept](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/intro/intro_keyconcepts.html).
Bintray is in a massive use by the OSS community thanks to its amazing platform and the wide range of REST API calls it offers.